# Git mirror as "gateway repository"

Tags: git

I need to work with a git repository, where the upstream master repo is located in some closed network to which I don't have direct access. I can access it only via a gateway server. Let's denote the involved machines:

- A: My local computer on which I'm coding
- B: Gateway server
- C: Upstream master server

My idea was to create a git mirror on B:

```
B$ git clone --mirror address-of-C:my-repo.git
```

On A I would clone normally from B then:

```
A$ git clone address-of-B:my-repo.git
```

**But how to keep B and C in sync?** First, in push-direction I imagined it easy by putting a post-receive hook on B, which pushes the received changes further to C:

```
#!/bin/bash
git push origin
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
  echo 'Mirroring failed!'
  exit 1
fi
```

However, this fails horribly if the push in the hook fails due to upstream conflicts, leaving me in a strange state in which I should perform a merge in the bare repository in B. I tried to mitigate this my doing a `git fetch` in the pre-receive hook, but this fails with a message `error: ref updates forbidden inside quarantine environment`.

Second, in the pull-direction I have no idea how to do this at all, because there is no such thing as a "pre-pull" hook. My only idea is to periodically pull by a cron-job, but this sounds not really right to me.

Any ideas how to solve such a case? I'm not a git expert, but I assumed with the myriad of options and features of git there should be some way to do this.

Comment: Would you be allowed to tunnel to C through B, e.g. using an SSH tunnel, or stunnel or similar?

Comment: Awesome hint, SSH-tunneling works perfectly for this scenario - I wasn't aware of it! Thank you so much. If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't technically answer the question of setting up a synchronized mirror, but you may be able to tunnel to C via B, using SSH tunneling or similar.